# in node.js express, how to tell the HTTP request is application/json or html on the content negoition in jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

I want my node.js server to send different content based on request's content type, my server code is like this

```
    if(req.accepts('text/html')){
        console.log("accepts('text/html')");
        locals.page = 'posts';                  
        res.render('question.ejs', locals.questions);
    }
    else if(req.accepts('application/json')){   
        console.log("'application/json'");          
        res.json(200,locals.questions);
    }
```

There is a similar post but only for android client
[in node.js express, how to tell the HTTP request is application/json or html on the content negoition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761861/in-node-js-express-how-to-tell-the-http-request-is-application-json-or-html-on)

This is my Jquery code

$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/course/abc/questions", 
       contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType:"json",
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data.length,data);
       }
     });

For some reason, even I set the content type on appication/json, the node.js server side still accepts html rather than json.

A little strange

Answer (score 2):

The headers are different on the GET request (jquery) vs the response (express). On the request/browser/jquery/ajax side, when making a GET request, you set the [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) header, meaning "I would like to get back one of these formats". There is no `Content-Type` header because a GET request has no body, thus that header is not applicable.

On the server side, you set `Content-Type`, meaning "this response body is of the following format". The semantics of accept can be a list of alternative formats, whereas content-type is just a single value.

Here's a snippet copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6692376/266795)

```
$.ajax({
    headers: { 
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    success : function(response) {
        ...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth brushing up on your [header field definitions](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)...

I question whether you really should be returning content-type based on the `Content-Type` header.

**TLDR;**

- `Accept` - used by the requestor to specify which media types are acceptable for the response
- `Content-Type` - indicates the media type of body that the requestor is sending to the recipient

So my first recommendation - use the right tool for the job, send the `Accept` header in the request.

Now, you can make use of the [`req.accepts`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.accepts) express function, which was built to do exactly what you want (i.e. ask the client what data format they prefer).

e.g.

```
const accept = req.accepts(['html', 'json'])
if (accept === 'html') {
    // res.send(...)
} else if (accept === 'json') {
    // res.json(...)
} else {
    // send 406 Not acceptable
}
```

Comment: This does not work with `Accept: accept: application/json; charset=utf-8`. I know, I was shocked myself when I realized my API was returning HTML instead of JSON for these requests

Comment: solved the problem with `req.get('accept').includes('application/json')`

Answer (score 0):

`req.accepts(['html', 'json'])` returns `false` when `Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8`

You can use something more robust like

```js
req.get('accept').includes('application/json')
```